# Node.js/Javascript Date() command returns garbled results after the first call

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I am having some problems with the Node.js/Javascript date function returning different results after the first call.

```
root@plug> node
> var date = new Date();
> date
Fri, 15 Jul 2011 22:55:09 GMT
> date
undefined, 15 Jul 2011 07.1953784e-317:60:09 GMT
> date
undefined, 15 Jul 2011 07.1953784e-317:02.89274756e-315:57 GMT
```

Even after I create a new date object, the formatting remains strange. It only seems to work once. Every subsequent call to it results in ill formatted date strings. I'm running 0.5.0-pre on a embedded Linux system (2.6.39.2) and it has a valid ntp time server and the system date command returns the correct date.

I'm just wondering why it gets messed up after the first call, and how to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: But there's only **one** call to the "Date()" function in what you've posted ...

Comment: Also when I try that in a much older version of Node, it doesn't do that. I suspect it's just a REPL problem.  You're only creating one "Date" object, and getting its value repeatedly should of course return the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce in node version 0.4.7.  Probably a 0.5.0-pre bug.  May have already been fixed. Try the latest version.  If you can still reproduce, search the node.js issue list to see if it's been filed.  If not, file an issue for it.